# Нумерация номера заказа в магазине

Tags: php

Была поставлена задача магазина с формированием номера заказа следующим образом:

> <год><месяц><день><порядковый номер за день>

Например:

> 20120105**1**
>   20120105**2**

Я спроектировал в базе это поле - числом. Оно же идет как первичный ключ и внешний ключ во многих таблицах.

И тут, при следующем усовершенствовании сайта, получил задачу другого алгоритма формирования номера, представимого только строкой.  Подскажите, как такие задачи правильнее всего решать? Как в движках они, например, решены?

Всем показывается "какой хотят" номер (как синоним), а хранится внутренний? Но тогда получается, что реальные номера будут совпадать, если сайт и его дочерние крутятся параллельно. Потому что сказали именно с приставками номер заказа делать.

Comment: У меня номер заказа идет как значение "auto-increment"-а.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что вопрос заключается в том, как реализовать [глобально-уникальный человеко-понятный идентификатор (slug)][1] для различных сайтов с единой базой?


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_(web_publishing)

Comment: нет, там про чистые url. Я именно про номера заказа в инет магазине

Comment: auto-increment это само просто так сделать, но заказчику такой номер не нравится

Comment: Если заказчик хочет поменять алгоритм формирования номера, когда во всю работает уже другой, меняйте, в чём проблема-то? Начнёте новую историю. Разве это так критично для интернет-магазина? :-)

Comment: новый номер - строкой представим, числом - нет. Форматы разные.
Строку нельзя записать в численный столбец.

Comment: > Я именно про номера заказа в инет магазине

Ну от того будут эти идентификаторы подставляться в url или в поле на сайте - суть не меняется.

В общем так и не понял в чем проблема хранить дополнительное уникальное поле в виде строки таким какое его хочет видеть заказчик и подставлять его в форму/url/email/etc.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы решал это следующим образом.

Одну колонку конечно вывел бы для автоинкремента.

Номер вида 201201052 - формировал сам в отдельную колонку и уже использовал по назначению =)

Ну и проблему "параллельно работающих счетчиков" решал бы с помощью GUID (не знаю, правда, как обстоят дела с ним в пхп)